# Vim upload on save like netbeans

Tags: vim, ftp

I've come across proj-vim which uses transmit-vim to upload project files. However, the readme doesn't tell me how to actually do this.

Ideally I'd like to keep the workflow I had with netbeans, where I have a local subset of the project. The files automatically upload to the server when I hit save.

Can I replicate that behaviour in vim, and if so, how?

Comment: I guess you mean this plugin: https://github.com/tmallen/transmit-vim. Do you actually fulfil the requirements (on a Mac, using the _Transmit_ application, etc.) Do you have the problem in configuring the server, or in triggering the upload?

Comment: I'm actually not sure where to start, proj-vim doesn't even give me an option for setting a remote project url or something like that... But I have transmit installed!

Comment: I'm no Mac user, so I can only guess, but it looks like the Transmit application should handle this. All transmit-vim does is `tell application "Transmit" open filename`, there's no configuration on the Vim side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know a command for uploading a file it is just as easy as

```
augroup AutoUpload
    autocmd! BufWritePost * :{TransmitFiles}
augroup END
```

, better with some stuff that checks whether you actually can transmit something (or `:silent!` in front of `{TransmitFiles}` if you are sure that command will just throw error in case nothing can be transmitted and won’t break anything).

**Update**: Seems that it should look like

```
augroup AutoUpload
    autocmd! BufWritePost * :silent! call TransmitFtpSendFile()
augroup END
```

: I do not see a straightforward way to check whether something may be transmitted.